# Нужно ли после слова "район" (при его сокращении до р-н) ставить точку?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли после слова район (если оно пишется сокращенно как р-н) ставить точку (если это не конец предложения). 
Вариант 1: Серпуховской р-н, г. Особый
или 
Вариант 1: Серпуховской р-н., г. Особый

Какое правило русского языка нужно использовать при поиске ответа на этот вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Не нужно, конечно. Точка ставится, если сокращение выражено урезанием концовки слова, например "зам.", "тов." и т.д. Здесь же присутствует окончание слова, поэтому точка не ставится.